# Spark dataframe version of pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I have a dictionary of the following structure

```
dictio = {"name":["name1","name2"],
          "tAcc":[0.8,0.8],
          "eAcc":[0.8,0.8]}
```

I want to convert this dictionary to a spark dataframe:

```
"name"   "tAcc"     "eAcc"
___________________________
"name1"   0.8       0.8
"name2"   0.8       0.8
```

the pandas function
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) does this job.
Does a spark version of this function exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use anything else than intermediate Pandas `DataFrame` here (where `spark` is a `SparkSession` instance):

```
spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data))
```

For any practical application having in memory dictionary will a bottleneck anyway, and should be abandoned for any but simplest, real-life applications.